# Différence entre « compter » et « dénombrer »

Tags: sens, vocabulaire, usage

Pourriez-vous m'aider à comprendre la différence entre « compter » et « dénombrer » ? Notamment,

```
3000 personnes en situation de rue ont été dénombrées par les équipes déployées.
```

et

```
3000 personnes en situation de rue ont été comptées par les équipes déployées.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dénombrer est un quasi synonyme de compter. On insiste sur la précision de la mesure car quand on dénombre, on est censé compter un par un les éléments.